# How do i write a trigger before insert to check for duplicates checking 6000+ records

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

what i came up with so far

```
CREATE TRIGGER no_duplicate BEFORE INSERT ON street_master
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF(EXISTS(SELECT id from street_master WHERE name=NEW.name))
THEN ;
END IF;
END
```

what should i write in 'then' part i get syntax error everytime i write  select statement or any other......

Comment: @eggyal..please elaborate...i have been thinking on this for hours and not geting any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [IF Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/if.html):

> Each ***`statement_list`*** consists of one or more SQL statements; an empty ***`statement_list`*** is not permitted.

You *could* consider using [`SIGNAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/signal.html) to raise an error, or else deliberately perform an erroneous operation (like calling a non-existent procedure).  But that's the *wrong way* to solve this problem.

What you really want is to define a `UNIQUE` index.  As documented under [CREATE INDEX Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-index.html):

> A `UNIQUE` index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a key value that matches an existing row.

Thus:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniqueNames ON street_master (name);
```

Comment: 'id' is my unique constraint... so in the if statement Trying to retrieve the 'id' of the duplicate, if exists, that is OLD.name = NEW. name where 'name' is street name and in the table street_master. I just want to match two strings before insert..one is while i insert new and second is the one from database

Comment: `UNIQUE` is the way to go here.

Comment: name is a user input and 'id'->UNIQUE is defined by the system automatically.....so i have to match 'name' with the existing records before i Insert a new record in the table

Comment: @PrathameshSarang: Yes, and..?  Why don't you actually ***try*** what we're suggesting?!

Comment: @eggyal i really appreciate it but i think sir u r not getting my problem....'name is what i want to search ' because there already exist a UNIQUE Constraint 'id' which is assigned automatically, data is submitted by a form...

Comment: @PrathameshSarang: I think I understand your problem perfectly, but you don't understand my answer.  Why don't you actually ***try*** what we're suggesting?!